# How to "drop" a completed list item - conditional formatting without designer

Tags: list, content, designer

I have a list I'm populating; for example, let's say I'm trying to keep track of new hires in Sharepoint. I have the hire's name, status of hire, etc. When I finally choose from the "status of hire" column that this candidate is "hired," I want the candidate to just disappear off the screen, so that only new hires who have not completed the hiring process are visible. Is there a way to do this without using designer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Designer for this.  You can create a view on your list.  In the list settings, create a new view and in the filter section of the view set it up to look something like:

> `Status of hire` not equals `Hired`

Then save your view.  If you want you can set this view as your default as well.  Keep in mind, people that you change to `Hired` are still in the list.  Just not visible in your new view.